# Filter forwarded messages in Gmail for the previous sender

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

I am not able to access work email (Exchange) on my mobile phone due to corporate policy.

Because of that I forward copies of those  messages to my Gmail account.

The forwarded messages are all received in Gmail  with "FW:" prepended to their  subjects.

In Gmail I would like to organize these messages using labels tied to the sender.

For example, if the message contains `From: john, doe <john.doe@my.company.com>` I would like to label it `john doe`.

I have encountered the following problem:

1. Including `From:` in the SEARCH causes Gmail to look at the sender address which is always my corporate address since I'm forwarding them therefore a match isn't made.
2. I would like to label only messages that start with the search string and not ones that contain it further down to avoid matching messages that are actually  responses to messages they originally sent.

Is this possible with Gmail filters?

If not, is there a script that can do this job?

Comment: Can you clarify the options that *are* available to you to access Exchange? For example, corp PC on or off corp network, OWA on/off corp network, Outlook mobile on/off corp network, Is the restriction a rule, a restriction that requires corp hardware, corp network, VPN, etc?